# Ordinal Logistic Regression Interpretation in R

Tags: r

I would like to know how best I can interpret results from Ordinal Logistical Regression.

I have an example from survey data from the MASS package below.

```
# loading MASS package
library(MASS)

# regression to determine if how much the student smokes is dependent on how often the student exercises
survey %>% 
  mutate(Exer = factor(Exer, levels = c("None", "Some", "Freq")),
         Smoke = factor(Smoke, levels = c("Never", "Occas", "Regul", "Heavy"))) %>% 
  polr(Smoke ~ Exer, data = ., Hess = TRUE) %>% 
  summary()

Call:
polr(formula = Smoke ~ Exer, data = ., Hess = TRUE)

Coefficients:
           Value Std. Error t value
ExerSome -0.4471     0.5765 -0.7756
ExerFreq  0.1867     0.5436  0.3434

Intercepts:
            Value   Std. Error t value
Never|Occas  1.3272  0.4997     2.6558
Occas|Regul  1.9468  0.5137     3.7899
Regul|Heavy  2.9630  0.5657     5.2378

Residual Deviance: 333.3227 
AIC: 343.3227 
(1 observation deleted due to missingness)
```

How should I interpret the coefficients (None, Some, and Freq) and intercepts (Never - Heavy)?

Is there another way I could incorporate the p-values during the decision making (significance / non-significance)?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/ gives an nice intro

Comment: Thanks @user2957945. This is so helpful.